# azure pipeline trigger release to stage as pre conditions for automated tests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a build and release pipelines for different services (A, B)
And every services have Test, QA, Alpha and Prod stages.

I have a build pipeline which run automated tests. The problem is, that tests only work on QA (Test environment unstable, mocked 3rd parties, etc).

Is it possible, that a build pipeline trigger other release pipelines to deploy to 'QA' then start the test, end of the test deploy to test (for tester)

In classis view - because as you read.. I am not a devops guy..

Comment: A build pipeline can trigger multiple release pipelines based on the flow you create. You can change your triggers on the release pipeline under artifacts. The artifact would be the build pipeline which will trigger the release pipeline. I am not sure if this is the question that you ask

Answer (score 0):

Yes a build pipeline can trigger multiple pipelines. You just need to create the appropriate triggers on the release pipelines. You can use the build pipelines artifact in all of the release pipelines you need to have triggered.

Once you add the build pipeline artifact to the release pipeline you can click on the lightening bolt and set up continuous deployment. You can do this on multiple release pipelines at the same time.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#release-triggers) is the Microsoft documentation on CD triggers.

[image: Release Pipeline Trigger]